# RabbitMQ - tons of open channels

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

We have an issue with RabbitMQ on both the producer and the consumer side where over time tons of channels are created and never closed.

We have our IConnection Ninjected with InSingletonScope and we have a single producer that disposes the model immediately.

Any insight into why this may be happening?

[image]

Connection Code:

```
    Bind<IConnection>()
        .ToMethod(ctx =>
                  {
                      var factory = new ConnectionFactory
                                    {
                                        Uri = ConnectionString,
                                        RequestedHeartbeat = 15,
                                        //every N seconds the server will send a heartbeat.  If the connection does not receive a heartbeat within
                                        //N*2 then the connection is considered dead.
                                        //suggested from http://public.hudl.com/bits/archives/2013/11/11/c-rabbitmq-happy-servers/
                                        AutomaticRecoveryEnabled = true
                                    };

                      return factory.CreateConnection();
                  })
        .InSingletonScope();
```

Publisher code:

```
 public void Publish(string exchangeName, string routingKey, IBasicProperties basicProperties, byte[] messageBytes)
    {
        using (var model = _rabbitConnection.CreateModel())
        {
            model.BasicPublish(exchangeName, routingKey, basicProperties, messageBytes);
        }            
    }
```

Rabbit Version: 3.5.1

C# RabbitMQ.Client: 3.5.2

Comment: I did see this change between version 3.5.2 and 3.5.6, not sure if it would have been around that.

https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/compare/rabbitmq_v3_5_2...rabbitmq_v3_5_6#diff-a43079ee2554d3ccb113c9214e7946adR662

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be fixed on C# RabbitMQ.Client 3.5.4

https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/issues/109